# node is not in primary or recovering state

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

My config file is:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    logAppend: true
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db
    journal:
        enabled: true
replication:
   replSetName: "rs0"
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
security:
     authorization: enabled
```

So, I'm successfully connecting via `mongod` process:
[image]

Then connecting to `mongo` and trying to open databases and collections:
[image]

And getting an error:

```
2018-07-07T15:40:25.092+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: {
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "node is not in primary or recovering state",
        "code" : 13436,
        "codeName" : "NotMasterOrSecondary",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"FshG5mLBvAQUizPHXGfCITV4ZKA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6573732769795407873")
                }
        }
}
```

To avoid this error, I'm using command `rs.initiate()` like:
[image]
But what does this error mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You've configured this node as a replica set member:

```
 replication:
     replSetName: "rs0"
```

On startup a new MongoDB server does not have a replica set configuration yet. The server will be in an
unknown [replica set member state](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-states/)
until you either [add this member to an existing replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/#add-a-member-to-an-existing-replica-set) configuration or
use `rs.initiate()` to establish it as the first member of a new replica set.

You can confirm the current state using `rs.status()`. A server without any
configuration will report something similar to the following in MongoDB 4.0
(the exact output may vary by server version):

```
> rs.status()
{
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "no replset config has been received",
    "code" : 94,
    "codeName" : "NotYetInitialized",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Once added to a replica set, you can use `rs.status()` and `rs.conf()` to check the current replica set status and configuration respectively.